# Getting blank page on using browser router and it's working when not using browser router for routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom, react-dom

In condole it says:

Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './pages/home';
import Navbar from './components/navbar';
import { BrowserRouter, Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Router>
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        </Router>
      </BrowserRouter>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you using the `<Link />` or  `<NavLink />` component in your navbar? If so you need to move it inside the `'<BrowserRouter>`. And also `<Router>` Should be `<Routes>`.

Comment: There are no link or navlink I am only using anchor tags in navbar and I have already tried moving navbar inside <BrowserRouter> and it's not working.

Comment: Typo, you are using a second router wrapped by the `BrowserRouter`, you only need one router for the entire app. Switch `Router` to `Routes` so the `Route` is correctly wrapped by a `Routes` component. The hooks warning is because you didn't pass required props to the `Router`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Comment: actually using a <Router> inside the <BrowserRouter> is the syntax that I found on internet. It said that it is the syntax after react router version 6 and above, so I don't think it's a typo

Comment: What you found on the internet would be incorrect then. In RRDv6 it's an invariant violation to render any router within another router.

Comment: On your advice I tried wrapping it inside both <Router> and <BrowserRouter> separately and it is still not working do you have any other solution that I can try ? if you do please let me know it would be of great help.

Comment: Tried wrapping *what* inside both `Router` and `BrowserRouter`? You need to remove the `Router` component, and import and use in its place the `Routes` component.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change "Router" to "Routes". Also use "exact" in the "Route"-Component.

I always do it like that.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Home } from './components/home/Home';

...

<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" exact element={<Home></Home>} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
...
```

If this doesn't help you can maybe find your solution here: [https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#:~:text=Hooks%20can%20only%20be%20called,of%20React%20and%20React%20DOM.&text=You%20might%20have%20more%20than,React%20in%20the%20same%20app.](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#:%7E:text=Hooks%20can%20only%20be%20called,of%20React%20and%20React%20DOM.&text=You%20might%20have%20more%20than,React%20in%20the%20same%20app.)

Comment: RRDv6 routes are ***always*** exactly matched. There is also no `exact` prop for the `Route` components.